# How do I graph on custom plots in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am using a plot obtained from the following site:
https://github.com/statsbylopez/blogposts/blob/master/fball_field.R
I do not know how to plot points on this. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You must explain clearly what points and where you want to plot. Otherwise we are going to need to revise our answers multiple times once you say that you want something else. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: In terms of what I want to plot, for instance I want to plot (0,0) and have that be at the center of the field. I do not know where to begin and thus havent tried anything

Comment: One point at the center would be `geom_point(data = data.frame(x = 0, y = 50), aes(x = x, y = y))`. So that is all then?

Comment: @ArnavHarkenavvy I just looked at your last posts. You seem to be struggling with the basics of R. Maybe try a course to strengthen your skills before you start with more advanced stuff? I can very much recommend "R Programming" on Coursera as a first step.

Answer (score 3):

*«...and thus haven't tried anything.»* — Well, then just do that: try! You cannot fail!

```
base.football + 
    geom_point(aes(1:10, seq(1, 100, 10)), color = "red") + 
    geom_point(aes(0, 50), color = "blue")
```

[image: 1]

#### Data

```
library(ggplot2)
theme.football <- function(){
    theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
          axis.text.y = element_text(angle=270, hjust=0.5), 
          panel.border = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = 'solid',
                                          colour = "black"), 
          axis.ticks = element_blank()) 
}

xlim <- (160/3)/2
hash.width <- 3.3
hash.x <- (xlim + hash.width)/2

df.hash <- expand.grid(x = c(-1*xlim, -1*hash.width, hash.width, xlim), y = (0:100))
df.hash <- df.hash %>% filter(!(floor(y %% 5) == 0))
base.football <- ggplot() + xlab("") + ylab("") + 
    theme_minimal() +
    annotate("segment", x = c(-1*xlim, -1*xlim, xlim, xlim), 
             y = c(-10, 110, 110, -10), 
             xend = c(-1*xlim, xlim, xlim, -1*xlim), 
             yend = c(110, 110, -10, -10), colour = "black") + 
    #geom_point(data = df.hash, aes(x, y), pch = 1) + 
    annotate("text", x = df.hash$x[df.hash$x < 0], y = df.hash$y[df.hash$x < 0], label = "_", hjust = 0, vjust = -0.2) + 
    annotate("text", x = df.hash$x[df.hash$x > 0], y = df.hash$y[df.hash$x > 0], label = "_", hjust = 1, vjust = -0.2) + 
    annotate("segment", x = rep(-1*xlim, 21), 
             y = seq(0, 100, by = 5), 
             xend =  rep(xlim, 21), 
             yend = seq(0, 100, by = 5)) +
    annotate("text", x = rep(-1*hash.x, 11), y = seq(0, 100, by = 10), 
             label = c("G   ", seq(10, 50, by = 10), rev(seq(10, 40, by = 10)), "   G"), 
             angle = 270, size = 4) + 
    annotate("text", x = rep(hash.x, 11), y = seq(0, 100, by = 10), 
             label = c("   G", seq(10, 50, by = 10), rev(seq(10, 40, by = 10)), "G   "), 
             angle = 90, size = 4) + 
    scale_y_continuous("", breaks = NULL, lim = c(-10, 110)) + 
    scale_x_continuous("", breaks = NULL, lim = c(-1*xlim, xlim)) + 
    annotate("rect", xmin=-1*xlim, xmax=xlim, ymin=-10, ymax=110, fill="palegreen", alpha=0.1)  + 
    theme.football()
```